# Extern Symbol Value Automatically Assigned to the End of RAM

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, bsp, rtems

I do not understand why extern symbol equals to the end of ram which is defined in the linker.

In especially, i see that case in the rtems code below:

[extern symbol "rdb_start" definition - start.S - line 155 -157](https://devel.rtems.org/browser/rtems/c/src/lib/libbsp/sparc/shared/start/start.S?rev=348d1812ba3bb83e2be6a99a7c706c5ea3a9d784)

[extern symbol "rdb_start" usage - bspgetworkarea.c - line 23-41](https://devel.rtems.org/browser/rtems/c/src/lib/libbsp/sparc/shared/bspgetworkarea.c?rev=1246d791aba03a8af8c1ee7cb91cd14292638bb9)

For instance, when you define your RAM size 0x800000 in the linker and take your entry address as 0x40000000, then rdb_start value corresponds to the 0x407FFFF0 automatically. If you define any other symbol similar to the rdb_start and make it global as rdb_start, you see the same result. it's value is automatically assigned to 407FFFF0.

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question while trying to get RTEMS to run on a LEON3 processor.
After asking Gaisler (the people who manufacture the LEON3) I learned that `rdb_start` start stands for "remote debugger start" and is an externally set symbol. It is what's used to set the stack pointer when the program is directly loaded to RAM via a remote debugger (i.e. GRMON) or when unpacked from PROM via your bootloader (i.e. mkprom).

The stack pointer should generally be set to the end of memory - 1 word. The memory space for a LEON3 processor with 8 MB of RAM, for example, is generally between 0x40000000 - 0x407FFFFF and the stack pointer is set to 0x407FFFF0.

I was able to change the value of `rdb_start` by passing the -stack option to mkprom2 and by using the stack command within GRMON to set the value of the new stack pointer.

I hope this helps the next person trying to figure out what `rdb_start` in the context of RTEMS is!

Comment: Your answer came only 4 months after the question was asked, not “years”. Anyway, it seems useful, as you say, so there's no need to waste space on apologies.